# Cannot watch changes in observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic3, observable

To build an app with Ionic 3 I am retrieving some data from Firebase using Geofire and then creating an array with additional data. I would like to see when this array is populated so that I can stop the loading component as soon as the array returns some values to my page.

In the provider my function is as follows. I convert the array into an observable at the final return statement.

```
getNearby(lat, long, rad): Observable<any>  

var locations = [];
const firebaseRef: firebase.database.Reference = 
firebase.database().ref('/storeLocs/');    
const geoFire: any = new Geofire(firebaseRef);
  this.queryActive = geoFire.query({
    center: [lat, long],
    radius: rad
  });

this.queryActive.on("key_entered", function(key, 
location, distance) {
var dist: number = distance.toFixed(1);

firebase.database().ref(`/storeInfo/${key}/`)
.on("value", snap => {

locations.push({ 
  distance: dist,       
  description: snap.val().description,
  name: snap.val().name
});
return false;})});
this.locList = locations;
return Observable.of(this.locList);
}
```

This is the ts file of the page:

```
this.loading=this.loadingCtrl.create();
this.loading.present();
this.storeList = 
this.locProv.getNearby(44.642,-78.379, 50);
  this.storeList.subscribe(list => {
    if (list.length > 0) {this.loading.dismiss()};
    console.log(list);
    console.log(list.length);
  })
```

The data I retrieve in the storeList observable displays properly on my screen but console.logs shows [] and 0 respectively, and of course the loading controller is not dismissed.

My data shows properly on the screen. Therefore, storeList variable is updated when it is filled with data from the database but the subscribe doesn't really capture the update. I also checked if storeList is updated using setTimeout and when I check it (let's say) 500 ms later, the console log prints the array retrieved from database properly.

How can I watch changes in this observable so I can stop the loading controller when the data is retrieved from database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the `ready` event to cancel your subscription and call `dismiss`.

```
geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
  // This will fire once the initial data is loaded, so now we can cancel the "key_entered" event listener
  geoQuery.cancel();
});
```

Refer [GeoFire documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryoneventtype-callback)

You can use [fromEventPattern](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromeventpattern.md) to create the observable from the `key_entered` event and subscribe to that observable, where you can update your `storeList`.

You can put the entire GeoQuery as a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) which resolves when we get the `ready` event and is rejected after a timeout (don't forget to unsubscribe observable + cancel the queryRef).